# Scanner not working in loop

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, infinite

After testing, I found out that this little loop never ends:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int c = 1;                                   // initialize variable
                                             // and then
while(c != 0){                               // as long as its not 0
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    c = scanner.nextInt();                   // ask for a new value
}
```

This loop takes place in a simple program where I ask the user to enter numbers, store them, and when he enters '0', it returns the summation of all numbers. (I'm leaving the storing code apart, irrelevant to the problem)

This loop simply never ends, and in fact, I can't even enter a number.

**EDIT :** Apparently, running this loop while **testing** doesn't work. I tried it on a main() and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: there is **no** infinite loop with the code shown. when **0** is entered the loop will terminate as expected.

Comment: what is your question, what problem you want to solve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The code in the question is incomplete. You need to present code that indicates type of `scanner` and how it takes its value. Without these one can only answer your question based on assumptions.  Consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for improving the question.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw it is. I am running it with JUnit, it doesn't even ask for a number.

Comment: in this case the problem is not in your loop :) can you share more code please so we can understand where exactly the problem?

Comment: @infiniteRefactor I edited my question! Thanks

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw that's the only code relevant to the problem. Everything else is storing in a List and iterating it after the loop, not much. I seem to be having a conceptual error about the scanner, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

A Scanner has a buffer, this buffer is first-in-last-out, that means if you like to enter a `20` you must press <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. Between <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> is a small pause and the scanner has no idea whenever more numerals following (you might like to enter a `205`, so he is waiting for the next number).

To identify the end of the number, the scanner is waiting for some character that is not a number. A <kbd>Enter</kbd> is such a no-number indicating the end of the number you like to read using `nextInt`. Unfortunately a <kbd>Enter</kbd> is also a `String` that can be read.

If you enter <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> the `20` is part of the number but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is part of a String but still **in the buffer**. So after `20` the buffer contains a <kbd>Enter</kbd> and this is not a number. Because that is not a number the second `readInt` is waiting forever!

What you can do is flush the buffer to flush the unwanted <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Example:

```
int c = 1;                                   // initialize variable
                                             // and then
while(c != 0){                               // as long as its not 0
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);// construct without buffer
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    c = scanner.nextInt();                   // ask for a new value
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: As you might noticed in the history, I am not sure if first-in-first-out or first-in-last-out. Even if they have a solid reason I often am confused what it meant to be the first, chronological or in order of the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem remains the same. The fact that I can't even type a character is noticeable.